# Sweet Alert after saving data in PHP

Tags: php, sweetalert

I want to show sweetalert message after I saved data . But I encountered some issues . Please correct me it some part of my code . I'm using PHP as my backend language and MYSQL as my database. This is my USER_SAVE.php . I already search for same scenario I already try the code it doesn't work for me may be the code is already deprecated or using other versions of sweetalert or what.

```
 <html>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.rawgit.com/t4t5/sweetalert/v0.2.0/lib/sweet-alert.css'>


<?php session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['id'])):
    header('Location:../index');
endif;

include('../dist/includes/dbcon.php');
$rec= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['rec']);
$bdo= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['bdo']);
$can_name= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['can_name']);
$po_ti= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['po_ti']);
$client= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['client']);
$rdr= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['rdr']);
$de= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['de']);
$remarks= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['remarks']);
$f_back= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['f_back']);
$datee= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['datee']);
$status= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['status']);
$tnum= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['tnum']);



$query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM accounts_at WHERE can_name='$can_name'")or die(mysqli_error());
$count=mysqli_num_rows($query);
if ($count>0)
{ 
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Account already exist');</script>";
    echo "<script>document.location='index'</script>";
}
else{
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO accounts_at(id,tnum,rec,bdo,can_name,po_ti,client,rdr,de,remarks,f_back,datee,status)
        VALUES(NULL,'$tnum','$rec','$bdo','$can_name','$po_ti','$client','$rdr','$de','$remarks','$f_back','$datee','$status')")or die(mysqli_error($con));

    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO accounts_at_action(id,tnum,rec,bdo,can_name,po_ti,client,rdr,de,remarks,f_back,datee,status)
        VALUES(NULL,'$tnum','$rec','$bdo','$can_name','$po_ti','$client','$rdr','$de','$remarks','$f_back','$datee','$status')")or die(mysqli_error($con));

    /*echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
    alert('Successfuly added new applicant');</script>";*/
    echo "
<script type='text/javascript'>
 setTimeout(function () { 
 swal('Successfully Added a Account!')
 },1); 
 window.setTimeout(function(){ 
  window.location.replace('index.php');
 } ,3000); 
</script>";

//  echo "<script>document.location='index'</script>";
}


?>
  <script src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/t4t5/sweetalert/v0.2.0/lib/sweet-alert.min.js'></script>

</html>
```

Comment: `But I encountered some issues` which were? Please provide details of what exactly isn't working vs what your expectations were.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: See there must be an issue with your query only, try printing number of rows which you are getting, I tried this and it worked $a =1;
if($a>0)
{
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Hello this is greater than 0');</script>";
}
else
{
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Hello this is less than 0');</script>";
}

Comment: You don't need a `setTimeout()` around your `swal()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your mysqli_query is send some error and make the page die. "or die(mysqli_error($con));"

So the page not running anymore to the bottom.
I Already clearing your code without any query just PHP to echo the script and it's works fine.

```
<html>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.rawgit.com/t4t5/sweetalert/v0.2.0/lib/sweet-alert.css'>
    <?php
        echo "
        <script type='text/javascript'>
        setTimeout(function () { 
            swal('Successfully Added a Account!')
        },1); 
        window.setTimeout(function(){ 
            window.location.replace('index.php');
        } ,3000); 
        </script>
        ";
    ?>
    <script src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/t4t5/sweetalert/v0.2.0/lib/sweet-alert.min.js'></script>
</html>
```

You can check your query with echo the result

```
echo mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO accounts_at(id,tnum,rec,bdo,can_name,po_ti,client,rdr,de,remarks,f_back,datee,status)
    VALUES(NULL,'$tnum','$rec','$bdo','$can_name','$po_ti','$client','$rdr','$de','$remarks','$f_back','$datee','$status')");
```